# Function generator for PC soundcards

Tags: windows-7, audio, ubuntu-10.04

I'm  in need of a [function generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_generator), but I want to avoid buying dedicated laboratory instrument. My idea is to use computer's sound card to create signals (yes, I know that it's not a replacement for the real thing). I'll most likely need just simple sines, squares, sawtooths and similar.

So I'm looking for a program which can generate waveforms and should work on windows 7 or Ubuntu 10.04. If it's free software, then it's a plus.

To me Audacity looked like obvious solution, but I'm hoping that there is a program which can display how the emitted wave looks like and can generate sound in real time (I know that shape of the wave can be solved with a prerecorded audio and clever visualizations).

Comment: I'd point out that, depending on the sensitivity of your usage of the outputs here, that it might be problematic if the machine hiccups or a process hangs momentarily or you have DPC's causing stutter in audio output.  I suspect a function generator is RIDICULOUSLY expensive compared to even a high-end stable PC though, but just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SigJenny](http://www.natch.co.uk/downloads/SigJenny/SigJenny.html) is a nice, free tool for generating continuous or burst signals from a PC sound card. Also [AF Signal Function Generator](http://www.dsp4swls.de/sigen/signalgeneng.html) which is nice, but no waveform display. You could always export to .wav, import in to Audacity and it'll show you the waveform in the track view. Both are Windows-only.

Comment: SigJenny won't detect my audio output on windows 7. AF seems to be working.